# localhost/wp-admin on my local redirects to production site's /wp-admin

Tags: admin

So when I go on localhost, my development environment loads fine. But when I try to go to `/wp-admin`, I get redirected to the production URL `mysite.com/wp-admin`. Where is this being set? I don't want to be redirected.

Comment: Do you have phpmyadmin? Search for other site URL in entire database. Probably somewhere in options.

Comment: Yeh I do have it. I found it in options too, one called `siteurl` and one called `home` and a few more to specific paths. Which one do I change?

Comment: @Edmund Both. Changing just these two will suffice for basic operation on localhost, though links within posts & elsewhere will still point to production site.

Answer (score 3):

You can find and replace instances of the old URL in your database but it's best to use a tool that handles serialized data such as [BackupBuddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) to avoid breaking things like some plugins. Hope this helps!

Comment: [Velvet Blues Update URL's](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) is also a great tool to accomplish this. I always use this when moving sites.

Answer (score 1):

Use find and replace to find instances of your old URL and update to your new URL.

Here is a decent article on it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

I wrote a little script that will create the necessary SQL code to put in phpmyadmin's SQL box (please backup DB first though)

http://tools.morningstarmediagroup.com/find-replace/

#### Note:

You'll just want to search for the top-level domain like so: `http://example.com` and replace with `http://new.example.com` - not a good idea to involve any trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using [WP CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/). 
Just run

```
wp search-replace old-domain.com new domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Too bad WP doesnt provide in-built configs for production and local envs like PHP frameworks. 
You'll have to change `siteurl` and `home` in `wp_options` to the production site URL